# How to update object state using useState hook

Tags: reactjs

Trying to update an objects state via the useState hook but it does not seem to be working. Just wondering if anyone can spot what I'm doing wrong here:

This is my useState:

```
const [selectState, setSelectState] = React.useState({
  level1: 0,
  level2: 0,
  level3: 0,
});
```

Component where I'm trying to update State:

```
<Button
   onClick={() => setSelectState({ ...selectState, level: 1 })}
   selected={selectState === 1}
   text="Blue"
 />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see couple of problems in your code:

- `setSelectState({ ...selectState, level: 1 })` - you are updating the `level` property but it is not present in the state. So you are adding a new property in the state instead of updating the existing one.
- `selected={selectState === 1}` - `selectedState` is an object. So you are comparing a number with an object and because of strict equality operator (`===`), the following condition:

  ```
  selectState === 1
  ```

  will never evaluate to `true`.